# Display progressbar until the next activity starts

Tags: android, android-activity, loading, android-progressbar

I have two activities. `Actvity1` and `Activity2`. `Activity2` ***contains heavy components*** therefore it takes some time open up the `Activity2` after user giving instructions to go `Activity2` from `Activity1`.

In the current implementation ( *actually no special code there. Only `startActivity(intent)` is used to lauch the next activity*) `Activity1` ***keep freezing*** until `Activity2` starts. I think AsyncTask can not be used because I have no parameters to execute AsyncTask. I just want to show progressbar circle until the next activity starts. Could you please give any answers.

Comment: Quick question: what sort of component is so big that it makes the UI freeze? You may want to start the activity with fewer components at first and then start those componenents in an async task or service.

Comment: It has a metrix of EditTexts. User can define the size (size<30). If the size is 30, there would be 900 editTexts.

Comment: It would be a good practice if I'll be able to implement in this way. I'll try use async task.

Comment: Yeah a lot better if you build all those elements after the activity is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a fragment taking all the space of your activity with a transparent background and the spinner in the middle.

You simply set it up before starting the new activity and it will spin until the first activity is ended.

But it may show a frozen spinner since the UI thread is used by starting the new activity. Let me know if it works I am actually interested in the outcome.

EDIT : 
Actually a better solution would be to create the activity without all the heavy components, and then create those components in an AyncTask.

It will be a lot smoother for the user.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it and let you know :)